# Custom UserManager always return null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to create my own `UserManager` extending from the original, and when I do a search by email, the user is not found. But if I do a search from the context, if I find the user (see the `Get` method). To verify that it is really well implemented, I overwrote the `FindByEmailAsync` method and it is really being called, but I do not know why the user can not find it. Some help? Thank you!

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection servicesCollection)
{
    servicesCollection.AddDbContext<MyIndentityContext>(currentOptions =>
        currentOptions.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    servicesCollection.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyIndentityContext>()
        .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
        .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
        .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
        .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
        .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        ...

        ...

        ...
}

public class MyIndentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyIndentityContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IConfiguration configuration)
        : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Sample.API");
    }

}

public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole> roleStore,
        IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<ApplicationRole>> roleValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors, ILogger<ApplicationRoleManager> logger) : base(roleStore,
        roleValidators,
        keyNormalizer, errors, logger)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        ILogger<ApplicationSignInManager> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) : base(userManager,
        contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher,
        IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<ApplicationUserManager> logger) :
        base(userStore, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors,
            services, logger)
    { }

    // Custom implementation to check if you are really calling the method
    public override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByEmailAsync(string email)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "A_NAME"
        });
    }
}

public class ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, MyIndentityContext>
{
    public ApplicationRoleStore(MyIndentityContext dbContext, IdentityErrorDescriber identityErrorDescriber)
        : base(dbContext, identityErrorDescriber)
    {}
}

public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, MyIndentityContext, string>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(MyIndentityContext dbContext, IdentityErrorDescriber identityErrorDescriber)
        : base(dbContext, identityErrorDescriber)
    {}

}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() { }

    public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName) { }

    public ApplicationRole(string roleName, string roleDescription) : base(roleName)
    {
        Description = roleDescription;
    }

}

[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors(CORS.AllowSpecificOrigins)]

public class UserController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager _applicationUserManager;

    public UserController(ApplicationUserManager applicationUserManager)
    {
        _applicationUserManager = applicationUserManager;
    }

     // GET: api/User/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<UserDTO> Get(int id)
    {

            var currentUser = await _applicationUserManager.FindByEmailAsync("example@example.com"); ==> RETURN NULL!

            var otherUser = _indentityContext.Users.Where(x => x.Email == "example@example.com"); ==> RETURN CORRECT USER!

            return currentUser;

    }

}
```

Comment: If you haven't already seen [Custom storage providers for ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers) that may give you some pointers.

Comment: `return Task.Run(...)` will never work.  I assume this is just sample code but try `return Task.FromResult(new ApplicationUser { UserName = "A_NAME" });` to get it working.

Comment: Could you share us a project? I made a test with your current code, it works correctly. Do you use multiple `DbContext`? Do you get User by `Task.Run(() => new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "A_NAME"
        });`?

Comment: @Edward Hi!, I'm only using one context. I added the Task.Run to verify that the FindByEmailAsync method is actually being called. That returns a user with Name "A_NAME". Later I leave a github link with the code.

Comment: @Edward Check the repository. https://github.com/avechuche/Sample.API.git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: This answer references code and values shown in your Github repro.*

When you call `UserManager.FindByEmailAsync`, the value you pass into the method is normalised - by default, this normalisation converts the value to uppercase. This normalised value is then used to search the `NormalizedEmail` column in the `AspNetUsers` table.

Inside of your `MyIndentityContext.OnModelCreating` method, you have the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(
    new ApplicationUser
    {
        Email = "a_mail@hotmail.com"
    });
```

As you're taking control of the data here and setting only `Email`, the `NormalizedEmail` value in the database is not being set (it's `null`). This means that when you use `UserManager.FindByEmailAsync` and are looking for `A_MAIL@HOTMAIL.COM` in the `NormalizedEmail` column, there's no match. However, when you use the `DbSet` directly and look at the `Email` column, you *can* find a matching record for `a_mail@hotmail.com`.

To resolve this, I recommend that instead of using `HasData` to seed your user(s), you use the `UserManager.CreateAsync` method inside of a seed method within your application. This will ensure that normalisation and other related processing occurrs as it should before the records are persisted in the database.